# One-to-one and one-to-many on the same entity in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I tried different ways to map an entity as `one-to-one` and `one-to-many` at the same time, but I had no luck.

I provided my models here:

```
public class Office
{
    public virtual Person Manager {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Person> People {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual Office Office{get;set;}
}
```

Could anybody guide me to write mapping via fluent api?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not necessary to define two different mapping for specific entities. All I need was to map a `one-to-many` relation via fluent api.

Here are the changes:

```
public class Office
{
    // fk field to the entity
    public Guid ManageId{get;set;}

    public virtual Person Manager {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Person> People {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
    // fk field to the entity
    public virtual Guid OfficeId{get;set;}

    public virtual Office Office{get;set;}
}
```

And by using fluent api:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Office>()
              .HasMany(d => d.People)
              .WithOptional(s => s.Manager)
              .Map(cs => cs.MapKey("OfficeId"));
```

Comment: Person does not contain the Manager, so the WithOptional does not even compile...

Comment: Please consider updating so that your answer can compile.